# mysql long query emailed before completion

Tags: mysql, shell, email

I have a MySQL query that has been running for about 4 days.  I enter the query from the command-line:

```
mysql -u who -p < SQL 
mail -s 'query completed' me@there < /dev/null
```

and got the email response before the query completed.  The mysql was not backgrounded.

Is it possible for a MySQL query to change its PID?  If not, any clue as to why the next command-line command would execute?

I know I could have done a mysql && mail and it would have waited for positive completion.

Comment: It's possible that the MySQL client aborted due timeout but the server still completes the query.

Comment: No, the query is still running.

Comment: You should probably add more info if you are looking for a solution, like what kind of query, where you are running the server and where the client, output of `show processlist;` etc. For that matter autocommit queries should not abort on connection loss, so your reply above does not clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to join these together with `&&` to ensure the second command doesn't fire unless the first succeeds:

```
mysql -u who -p < SQL && mail -s 'query completed' me@there < /dev/null
```

In your version the second command runs regardless.

Comment: That will make the email conditional on whether the query succeeds or fails, but both versions wait for the query to complete.

Comment: @Barmar What if the query times out after 300 seconds, or whatever the query limit is on that server's configuration? The client gives up before the query actually finishes, though this could be client specific as well.